# Pdf hash signing with iText 8.0.3

Tags: java, hash, cryptography, itext, digital-signature

I Would like to ask if there is an easy way to sign a hash using the 8.0.3 version of iText Java library. I have seen that they have recently added a high level API for pdf signatures that is PAdES-compliant but I am not sure about how I should sign hashes and keep the result separated from the respective document. This high level API that they have added introduces a class named PdfPadesSigner that is so useful to sign pdf documents but what I receive is the hash of a pdf document, not the document itself and what I have to return is the signature of the hash.

I need to sign hashes with the possibility to use this four conformance levels: B-B, B-T, B-LT, B-LTA. But I have not found anything on iText that allows me to do that. I don't even know how to include attributes to the signature as "commitment-type-indication", "content-hints", "mime-type", "signer-location", "content-time-stamp",... Something that I also need to do.

Comment: Don't say the latest version. A new version could be out at any time. Mention the specific version you are using.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using the 8.0.3 version

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *"what I receive is the hash of a pdf document, not the document itself and what I have to return is the signature of the hash ... I need to sign hashes with the possibility to use this four conformance levels: B-B, B-T, B-LT, B-LTA."* - In the context of PAdES that scenario does not make sense: You don't need the "hash of a pdf document" but you need the hash of the to-be-signed byte ranges of the PDF after preparation for signing, only then you can return a matching signature container the caller can inject into their prepared PDF. Thus, are you sure you want to create PAdES signatures?

Comment: *"include attributes to the signature as "commitment-type-indication", "content-hints", "mime-type", "signer-location", "content-time-stamp",... Something that I also need to do."* - This sounds even less like you're trying to create PAdES signatures. Probably you are asked to create detached CAdES signatures? In that case you should have a look at eSig DSS: https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/doc/dss-documentation.html https://github.com/esig/dss

Comment: Why do you say that it does not sound like trying to create PAdES signatures? If I am not wrong PAdES signatures can also contain that attributes. I have to offer both signing pdf documents and signing Signer Document Representations (digests) and it that attributes are passed to me I have to include them in the signature.

Comment: *"If I am not wrong PAdES signatures can also contain that attributes."* - "commitment-type-indication" indeed explicitly allowed; "content-hints" _shall provide information on the innermost signed content of a multi-layer message
where one content is encapsulated in another._ There are no such encapsulated contents in PAdES. "mime-type" _shall indicate the mime-type of the signed data._ There is no need for this, the signed data after all envelops the container. "signer-location" has the PDF equivalent Location in the signer dictionary which is preferred. ...

Comment: ... "content-time-stamp" is explicitly allowed. So, of the attributes you mentioned only  "commitment-type-indication" and "content-time-stamp" have been listed as explicitly allowed attributes for PAdES, and even them I've hardly ever seen in use. Thus, in most signature validators or viewers you shouldn't expect any support for attributes that are not on that list, in particular not for attributes that make no sense in the context of PAdES.

Comment: *"I have to offer both signing pdf documents and signing Signer Document Representations (digests)"* - for all baseline levels? How do you want to do LT, do you want to return all the vri for the caller to build into his PDF? And how do you want to do LTA from scratch?