# Pdf hash sign with iText v8.0.3

Tags: pdf, itext

I am trying out iText java v8.0.3 trial version to sign pdf document. We first need to generate the document hash, and then send this hash to our signing server which returns a PKCS7 signature. We then apply this signature on the original pdf document.

In iText documentation, it is mentioned about PdfPadesSigner class's prepareDocumentForSignature() and addSignatureToPreparedDocument() methods, which I believe would serve our purpose. But the class does not seem to include those methods, when I build against iText v8.0.3 maven dependency.

I tried using v5.5.13.3 PdfPKCS7 getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes method, but I am getting "document has been altered" signature validation error. Also I have no signing certificate to pass to PdfPKCS7 constructor. So checking out the latest version if it directly supports it.

I also saw this question:
[Pdf hash signing with iText 8.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77983309/pdf-hash-signing-with-itext-8-0-3)

Kindly help with sample code/APIs to implement this flow.

**Here is my code** Step 1: hash generation:

```
pdfTwoPhaseSigner =  new PdfTwoPhaseSigner(new PdfReader(inputStream), new FileOutputStream(tmpFileName));
    
SignerProperties signerProperties = new SignerProperties();
signerProperties.setPageRect(new Rectangle(36, 748, 144, 780));
signerProperties.setFieldName("swa");
signerProperties.setReason("test reason");
signerProperties.setLocation("test location");
        
SignatureFieldAppearance signatureFieldAppearance = new SignatureFieldAppearance("swa");
signatureFieldAppearance.setContent("Test Name", "Test description");    signerProperties.setSignatureAppearance(signatureFieldAppearance);`        
byte[] digestedDocumentBytes = pdfTwoPhaseSigner.prepareDocumentForSignature(signerProperties, "SHA256", PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite, PdfName.Adbe_pkcs7_detached, (8192 * 2 + 2), true);      // ETSI_CAdES_DETACHED
return digestedDocumentBytes;
```

Step 2: remote hash signing: returns: byte[] pkcs7, X509Certificate[] chain

Step 3: apply signature to pdf

```
CMSContainer cms = new CMSContainer();
SignerInfo signerInfo = new SignerInfo();
signerInfo.setSigningCertificate(chain[0]);
signerInfo.setSignature(pkcs7);
signerInfo.setDigestAlgorithm(new AlgorithmIdentifier(DigestAlgorithms.getAllowedDigest("SHA256")));
cms.addCertificates(chain);
cms.setSignerInfo(signerInfo);
    
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
try (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(new FileInputStream(tmpFileName)))) {
PdfTwoPhaseSigner.addSignatureToPreparedDocument(document, "swa", outputStream, cms);
}
finally {
outputStream.close();
}
```

Result: The document has been altered or corrupted since the Signature was applied

Comment: Have you tried something like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57168641/1729265) (or the equivalent Java version [here](https://github.com/mkl-public/testarea-itext7/blob/master/src/test/java/mkl/testarea/itext7/signature/SignExternally.java))?

Comment: Indeed, the `PdfTwoPhaseSigner` proposed by @LionelRichTea should also be usable.

Comment: Thanks @mkl, let me try them out and get back

Comment: In step three you use `pkcs7` as plain signature value of `CMSContainer cms`. But you also say that `pkcs7` actually is a PKCS7 signature, i.e. a CMS signature container. Thus, your `cms` wraps a full inner signature container where it should wrap a simple signature value. This must be invalid. Instead try loading `CMSContainer cms` directly from `pkcs7`!

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have been an incorrect link, the methods you're looking for are in the [PdfTwoPhaseSigner](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/java/8.0.3/com/itextpdf/signatures/PdfTwoPhaseSigner.html) class (or see [here](https://api.itextpdf.com/iText/dotnet/latest/classi_text_1_1_signatures_1_1_pdf_two_phase_signer.html) for the .NET API).

Have you also seen the recent [PAdES Signing API examples](https://kb.itextpdf.com/itext/pades-signing-high-level-api) on the iText Knowledge Base?

Comment: Thanks @LionelRichTea. When I call the instance method prepareDocumentForSignature() followed by static method addSignatureToPreparedDocument() of PdfTwoPhaseSigner, it cannot find the field, that I had set in SignerProperties.setFieldName() passed to prepareDocumentForSignature(). 

com.itextpdf.kernel.exceptions.PdfException: There is no field in the document with such name: swa.
 at PdfSigner$SignatureApplier.apply(PdfSigner.java:1527)
 at PdfTwoPhaseSigner.addSignatureToPreparedDocument(PdfTwoPhaseSigner.java:103)

I will check, it is probably a PdfReader issue?

Comment: @Swaran, are you able to share your code? Alternatively, you could check against the signing examples in the [twophase](https://github.com/itext/itext-publications-examples-java/tree/develop/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/samples/sandbox/signatures/twophase) repo

Comment: Thanks for helping, I will share code when I get to work tomorrow. But looking at the two-phase sample code, I definitely lack the certificate chain for cms container in the document preparation stage. In our workflow, we need to first calculate document hash and display to user, then after user authentication, send hash to our signing server to form csr, create key pair, create certificate, sign hash with pvt key, and return the signature and certificate together. Then apply the signature to original pdf. Any clues how to achieve this pls?

Comment: I have updated with my code, kindly check